# How to get attribute from another class using the browse method in OpenERP

Tags: python, orm, openerp-7

I've installed the oemedical addon in my OperERP 7. I'm adding some modifications on it.
I have a problem with the function **_get_ssn_from_name** that I have created in the appointment module, which gets the SSN from the *oemedical.patient* class to display it in *oemedical.appointment* view.

Here is the code of the class oemedical.appointment containing the function I've developed

```
class OeMedicalAppointment(osv.Model):
    _name = 'oemedical.appointment'

    # The function causing the problem
    def _get_ssn_from_name(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        res = {}
        ssn = ''
        for record in self.pool.get('oemedical.patient').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            # When patient is not yet specified
            if not record.lastname:
                ssn = 'No Patient Specified!'

            # Return the ssn when the caller is the field name
            if field_name == 'alias':
                if record.ssn:
                    ssn = record.ssn
                else:
                    ssn = "Not Specified"
                print("ssn : %s" % ssn)

            res[record.id] = ssn
        return res

    _columns = {
        'patient_id': fields.many2one('oemedical.patient', string='Patient',
                                   required=True, select=True,
                                   help='Patient Name'),
        'name': fields.char(size=256, string='Appointment ID', readonly=True),
        'appointment_date': fields.datetime(string='Date and Time'),
        'appointment_day': fields.date(string='Date'),
        # some other attributes
        'alias': fields.function(_get_ssn_from_name, type='char', string='SSN', help="Social Security Number", multi=False),
        # other attributes
    }

OeMedicalAppointment()
```

And here is the code of the class oemedical.patient

```
class OeMedicalPatient(osv.Model):
    _name='oemedical.patient'
    _inherits={
        'res.partner': 'partner_id',
    }

    _columns={
        'partner_id': fields.many2one(
            'res.partner', 'Related Partner', required=True,
            ondelete='cascade', help='Partner-related data of the patient'),
        'first_name': fields.char(size=256, string='Name', required=True),
        'lastname': fields.char(size=256, string='Lastname', required=True),
        # many other attributes..
        'ssn': fields.char(size=256, string='SSN'),
        # some other attributes..
        'deceased': fields.boolean(string='Deceased'),
    }

OeMedicalPatient()
```

Here is the interface of creation of new appointment :
[Interface of adding a new appointment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX9CE.png)

When I create a new patient on the Appointment creation form (the field where I can choose the patient in the screenshot), I doesnt't get an error and everything goes well, but when I try to create an appointment for an existing patient I get the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'Field lastname not found in browse_record(oemedical.patient, 8)'
```

Please help me, and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on the [official OpenERP Q/A forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-get-attribute-from-another-class-using-the-browse-method-in-openerp-57534) and the problem is solved.